# C# Adding items to list with .Any not working

Tags: c#

Hi I've been trying to fix this for a while now but I can't figure it out myself..

I'm trying to add new 'customers' to a List but the Id which the new customer has can not be the same as an Id which is already added to the list.

I've been trying to do this with the `.Any` method but I think I made a mistake somewhere..

```
if (AllCustomers.Any(x => x.id != pNewCustomer.id))
{
   // Add customer here
}
```

Comment: so `if` clause content is not executed ?

Comment: have you step through and ensured your if statement evaluates to true?

Comment: @Tigran It is being executed but it's not checking if the Id is already on the list. I can currently add 2 'customers' with the same id which is the problem Thanks in advantage

Comment: step through I bet pNewCustomer.id isn't what you expect it is

Comment: @prospector pNewCustomer.Id is just a number which i think is right

Comment: You either want not any match or all don't match.  You currently have any don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition tests if there is any customer in the AllCustomers list that has a value different from the new customer.

The condition you want is

```
if (!AllCustomers.Any(x => x.id == pNewCustomer.id))
{
    // Add customer here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `.All` method.

If you have:

```
var list = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
list.Any(x => x != 2); // TRUE because 1 != 2
list.All(x => x != 2); // FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (AllCustomers.Any(x => x.id == pNewCustomer.id))
{
    // already exists. Do not add
}
else
{
    AllCustomers.Add(pNewCustomer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Any`, use `All`:

```
if (AllCustomers.All(x => x.id != pNewCustomer.id))
{
       // Add customer here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
if (!AllCustomers.Any(x => x.id == pNewCustomer.id))
{
   // Add customer here
}
```

Please note != (Not Equal) has been replaced by == (Equals) and the condition itself is inverted by ! in the beginning.